# Formatting a cell based on perpendicular row/column values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Trying to create a Gantt chart look in Excel.  I have two columns, A and B (**A** = start date, **B** = End Date).

Across the top of the page (Row **2**) I have a column with a date for every date of the project (custom formatted with "d" for readability, with the name of the month in Row 1.)

I'm now trying to apply conditional formatting rules to turn the cell in the column a specific colour (say, green) if:

the value in A[this row] is greater-than-or-equal-to [this column]2.

*and*

the value in B[this row] less-than-or-equal-to [this column]2.

I've dug through a few answers recommending ADDRESS() and INDIRECT(), but I'm stumped on getting this to work.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AND` to combine the conditions. I'm assuming the 'Gantt chart' starts as from column C and the active row is 2 here.

Select C2 and the rest of the row (to 31, 30 or 28/29 depending on the number of days in the month).

Pull up conditional formatting with formula and put:

```
=AND(C2>=$A2,C2<=$B2)
```

Pick the format fill green and that should do it

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting if you use the first cell of your selection in the formula it automatically turns that into a relative formula.

For example if you use the formula: `=A1>5` and select cells `A1:B5` it will check **each** cell to see if its >5  not just cell `A1` (so it automatically increments the row and the column for you).  Usually this is preferred over using `indirect` but sometimes `indirect` is necessary.

So using `indirect` you can utilize the `row()` and `column()` functions.  So in your example:

> the value in A[this row] is greater-than-or-equal-to [this column]2.
>
> and
>
> the value in B[this row] less-than-or-equal-to [this column]2.

Would look like:

```
=AND(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()) >= INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&"2"), INDIRECT("B"&ROW()) <= INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&"2"))
```

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

It works for me without `ADDRESS` or `INDIRECT`. This is the formula inside the conditional formatting. If I have to guess what's going on, it's most likely that you are not placing the proper anchors (`$`).

```
=AND(C$2>=$A3,C$2<=$B3)
```